# Appending figcaption to lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to display an iframe of an youtube video inside an figcaption within an lightbox. It is working somewhat... it shows up but all of the figcaption in the page show up I want to select only the unique figcaption of each img

Here is a jsfiddle of my code 
`enter code here`https://jsfiddle.net/acef596/bx9gz55z/1/

It is displaying all the figcaptions at once, when i want only the figcaption of the img that is clicked on to bring up the lightbox.